# How to render components if condition in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I trying to add if statement nested in JSX. `condition ? true example : false example` works perfectly but when I change to `if(condition) { ... }` it display following error in console:

[image]

---

Example with one-line condition (working):
https://codepen.io/webloopbox/pen/MWmqJOV

If example (with error): https://codepen.io/webloopbox/pen/JjNevxj

---

Is it even possible to use if Statement inside JSX like under second link? What is the best method to display more than one component under a conditon?

Comment: `{show && (<><Person..../></>)}`

Comment: JSX tends to expect expressions, not blocks

Answer (score 0):

`{(condition) ? <div>true render</div> : <div>false render</div>}`

Comment: Hi, your answer needs more explanation check this link to find how to write a good answer at Stack Overflow: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.